# Problems with setdefault and Integers

Tags: python, tree

I'm testing the following function:

```
def getDataMapOfFirstLine(line):
    datamap = {}
    for item in line:
        hierarchy = item.split('^')
        partialmap = datamap
        i=0
        for node in hierarchy:
            partialmap = partialmap.setdefault(node, i)
            i += 1

    return datamap
```

It should create a dictionary out of the first line of a csv-file, that looks like this:

```
nummer;such;ans;bverb^konum;bverb^namebspr;bverb^bank^iident;
1213;HANS;Hans Dominik;111000222;Hans' account; DE2145432523534232;
1444555;DIRK;Dirk Daniel;13300002;Dirk's account; DE2134634565462352;
```

As you see these circumflex-signs in each semicolon-separated string are something like a join in SQL. If I execute it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./importtool.py", line 173, in <module>
    main()
  File "./importtool.py", line 38, in main
    analyseImportFile(importfile, parser, options)
  File "./importtool.py", line 119, in analyseImportFile
    datamap = getDataMapOfFirstLine(line)
  File "./importtool.py", line 149, in getDataMapOfFirstLine
    partialmap = partialmap.setdefault(node, i)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

If I replace the i in the setdefault-function by {} I get no error:

```
{'bverb': {'namebspr': {}, 'konum': {}, 'bank': {'iident': {}}}, 'such': {}, 'ans': {}}
```

This is nearly, what I want, but instead of the {} I would like to get a column-number.

I just don't get what is wrong. I tried this in interactive mode:

```
>>> mydict = {'foo': "Hallo", 'bar': 5}
>>> mydict.setdefault("sth", 12)
12
>>> print mydict
{'sth': 12, 'foo': 'Hallo', 'bar': 5}
```

As you see, this works...

I appreciate every help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to replace `partialmap = partialmap.setdefault(node, i)` with `partialmap.setdefault(node, i)`

Comment: Thanks it worked! It seems clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
partialmap = partialmap.setdefault(node, i)
```

`dict.setdefault` *returns* the thing that was set (or what was already there).  In this case, it's an integer so you're setting `partialmap` to an `int`.  You can probably just not grab the return value (which is what you've done in the interactive terminal BTW):

```
partialmap.setdefault(node, i)
```

Comment: Upps, now it seems obvious. My mistake. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Nils-o-mat -- No problem.  I'm happy to help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel so inclined :-)

Comment: Coming. Waiting for the timer to reach zero :-)